# Please tell me good linear algebra books which use the elementary divisors to prove the Jordan normal form theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, jordan-normal-form

I want to read linear algebra books which use the elementary divisors to prove the Jordan normal form theorem.

Please tell me good linear algebra books which use the elementary divisors to prove the Jordan normal form theorem.

Comment: I believe that Hoffmann and Kunze's "Linear Algebra" proves the existence of Jordan form in this way. I know that Dummit and Foote's "Abstract Algebra" proves the existence of Jordan form in this fashion, but that is not primarily a linear algebra book.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much for your information.